# Que signifie "sophie" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Bonjour,

Dans une lettre à Lucien Combelle (29 mars 1942), Céline écrit :

> Voyons-nous, en ce moment même, si délicat, Sûreté générale, Beaux-arts, si prompts à mes trousses, la Guerre, l'Intérieur, si facilement révoltés, Mgr Gerlier, la Légion, la Présidence, le moindrement s'émouvoir ?
> Cette bonne blague ! Au vrai patriote cependant, comme cette attitude est suspecte ! Que l'on me pardonne. Complices ? Peut-être... Réfléchissez... Pourquoi vient-on m'inquiéter ? Moi, chétif, infime ?
> Pour quelques bouffons propos ? Sabrer mes malheureux livres ?
> "Injures à l'armée" ? Lorsque vingt généraux superbes s'avancent à la
> barre du monde pour en clamer cent fois autant ? On me brûle trois
> mille exemplaires ? **Sophie !** À grands déplacements de gendarmes !
> Saisies, grondement de commissaires ! Salades ! Vous n'y êtes pas du
> tout ! On ne me reproche rien au fond que d'exister. Alibis, tout ce
> tremblement ! L'armée ? Et comment que l'on s'en fout ! Et de son
> honneur ! Et de son moral ! Pourris prétextes ! Vous allez voir un
> petit peu, pendant les six mois à venir, ce qu'on va faire déguster à
> l'armée jolie ! Ce qu'il en restera aux prunes ! Et la doulce France
> donc avec ! Vous m'en direz de nouvelles ! Auscultez pour les astres !

Savez-vous ce que signifie *Sophie* ici ?

Edit 11/12/21 :
En corroborant la réponse de @jlliagre, le mystère de *Sophie* est dévoilé aussi dans une note de cette lettre dans l'Année Céline 1995, p. 121, note 9.

[image]

Comment: Peut-on en avoir plus ? Ça manque de contexte. Parce qu'à part le prénom et une possible évocation de la sagesse...

Comment: Bien sûr, je vais copier le paragraphe.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr pour le sens ici. Mais je sais bien que sophie signifie sagesse. C'est un mot grec.

Comment: @Dimitris Merci. Pour le sens, je crois qu'il s'agit d'une ironie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Sophie* vient ici très probablement de l'expression argotique *[faire sa Sophie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_sa_Sophie#:%7E:text=Se%20comporter%20de%20fa%C3%A7on%20prude,la%20mani%C3%A8re%20d%27une%20mijaur%C3%A9e.)* qui signifie *faire des manières, faire le dégoûté*. Une expression similaire qui serait mieux comprise aujourd'hui est « jouer la vierge effarouchée ».

L'expression *faire sa Sophie* est présente dans le [Dictionnaire d'argot fin-de-siècle](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k109806d.texteImage) (Charles Virmaitre, 1894) et on la retrouve dans des ouvrages du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Une trace plus ancienne se trouve dans *le nouveau glossaire genevois*, 1852, où l'on peut lire :

> *SOPHIE. N'est usité que dans cette locution : Il fait sa sophie, c'est-à-dire : Il fait la demoiselle sage.*

Il existait donc peut-être à l'origine un lien entre sagesse et Sophie.

Comment: Peut-on dater cette expression ? Penses-tu qu'elle était courante en 1942 ?

Comment: Oui, elle existait déjà à la fin du XIXe siècle.

Comment: D'accord, merci !

Answer (score 3):

Sophie est un mot grec. Il signifie sagesse. Voir aussi sophisme et sophiste pour des mots de la même racine. Comme @Ovide le remarque, il peut exprimer l'ironie dans ce contexte. Dans le Littré on trouve :

*Dans un langage de mauvaise compagnie, faire sa sophie, (signifie) faire la prude.*

https://www.littre.org/definition/sophie

**Edit** (merci @jlliagre)

*C'est en grec que sophie signifie sagesse. En français, Sophie est uniquement compris comme un prénom dont le lien avec sagesse est peu connu. Sophisme et sophiste sont bien dérivés, via le latin, de mots eux mêmes dérivés du σοφία grec mais il n'est pas vraisemblable que Sophie ! ait pu signifier Sagesse ! de manière ironique dans le texte de Céline. L'expression argotique citée par Littré est en revanche la bonne piste.*

Comment: C'est en grec que *sophie* signifie sagesse. En français, Sophie est uniquement compris comme un prénom dont le lien avec sagesse est peu connu. Sophisme et sophiste sont bien dérivés, via le latin, de mots eux mêmes dérivés du σοφία grec mais il n'est pas vraisemblable que *Sophie !* ait pu signifier *Sagesse !* de manière ironique dans le texte de Céline. L'expression argotique citée par Littré est en revanche la bonne piste, je n'avais pas vu que tu l'avais déjà mentionné quand j'ai répondu, désolé.

Comment: Un dérivé de σοφία bien connu et que l'on retrouve dans la plupart des langues les plus parlées dans le monde est *philosophie* qui ne signifie pas *aimer Sophie* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

"Sophie" ne fait pas précisément référence à quelqu'un ou quelque chose de connu.
C'est une sorte d'interjection que Céline (et d'autres Français) utilisaient à cette époque et qui est aujourd'hui passée de mode. Il s'agissait de personnaliser l'exclamation en s'adressant à quelqu'un d'imaginaire qui porterait ce prénom. Le sens étant ici de s'adresser  à un personnage féminin faisant preuve d'une excessive candeur.
A titre d'autre exemple, voyez ci-dessous cet extrait des *Beaux Draps* :

> « C’est le mensonge qui nous fit tant de mal ! » Ô **Sophie !** Ce crime !
> Ils en ont tous vécu les tantes ! prospérés ! engraissés, bouffis !
> reluis à l’extase ! C’est à présent qu’ils se dégoûtent ? Mais ils
> peuvent pas vivre d’autre chose ! Ils sont foutrement incapables de
> vendre autre chose que du puant ! leurs lecteurs en voudraient jamais
> ! Le goût est fait !